# How to make Convolved Diffuse and Specular image in C#

Tags: image-processing, pbr, image, importance-sampling

I am trying to take either a HDR panoramic or HDR cubeMap and from that create a Lambert Irradiance environment map and a Cook-Torrence Specular environment map.

I am stuck at the proper implementation to get the samples using Hammersley and importance sampling and then placing them on my target image.

This is essentially a pre-filtering environment maps question in C#

Comment: here you are asking three different questions. one about generation of quasi-random number generation, one about importance sampling, and one about mapping from a 3d direction to a coordinate on an env map. Also, are your questions exclusively about implementation? do you understand those concepts and algorithms fully? What have you tried already? what worked and what didn't? It would help if you made what you're asking more clear.